# Google Drive JS - Making a request to export links

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api

I am trying to get the html out of files in drive using the Drive SDK. I am using the picker API and it works nice, I get the fileID of the file I want the HTML from.

However (as it is a native google file) it does not contain a downloadURL so I am using the exportlinks.

When trying to make a request to the export links (to get the html) I get cross domain error :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin...is therefore not allowed access.

The code I am using for this request is

```
xhr.open('GET',resp['exportLinks']['text/html']);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
                        xhr.onload = function() {

                            copied = 0;

                            hideLoading(false);

                            var html = xhr.responseText;
                            $('#result_html').attr('value',html);

                            var $name = $('#result_html').find(".title span").val();

                            var elements = $(html);
                            var title = $(elements);
                            var name = elements[0].innerHTML;

                            if($('#edit-title').val() == ""){
                                $('#edit-title').val(name);
                            }

                            $('#drive_doc_name').append(Drupal.t('Document selected') + " : " + name);

                        };

                        xhr.onerror = function() {
                            console.log("Error getting HTML");
                            hideLoading(true);

                        };
                        xhr.send();
```

Please help, I know exportLinks do not support cross browser requests but I do not know how to workaround this...any help would be much appreciated.

Best regards,
Joao Garin

Comment: By the way.I had this snippet was working until yesterday. I don't know if something changed meanwhile and why it would not work anymore with CORS using a normal XMLHttpRequest as mentioned in the API. I understand the issue (cross domain requests) but It seems like such a critical task..Anyone working with the Drive api will want to read files I guess..